# Accessing random nos from file and displaying on console?

Tags: c

The following code create a file file.text and prints the following in the file "

```
1 2 
3 4
```

What is the most efficient way to print the value 4 on the console. In actual case I have a 2000 x 2000 matrix, and I have to access let say the value [2000][1500] and print the same on console. by efficient I mean how quickly the pointer can go there, fetch the data, and send it to the display buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "1", "2", "\n" "3", 4);


   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it quickly you might need to assume the file is correctly filled. If you know your numbers are only 1 digit long you can multiply (2 (1 digit + 1 space) by the number of entries in one line + 1 (the `"\n"`)) by `y`: the number of the line you wish to get (in this case i think `2000`?) and then add (2 (same) times `x`).

If your numbers are not always 1 digit long, you need to read the file by chunks, count the `"\n"`'s and then count the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "file" need not be a text file, and the data to be stored need not be formatted in the form of matrix (i.e. including spaces and newlines).

You can do the following:

Step 1. Open file in binary mode.
Step 2. Write the matrix (suppose `A[2000][2000]`)data in the file using `fwrite`.
Step 3. Now your file is ready, you want to read element at position say `[1500][1000]`.
Step 4. That will be `((1500*2000) + 1000)th` integer written in the file, so use `fseek` to get the file pointer to that position.
Step 5: Read the integer from that position using `fread`.